# How to select data from a table based on multiple expressions?

Tags: oracle19c

I have a view by the name of  info and it's structure and data sample is the following:

| id | name | contacts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ali | 1234 |
| 1 | ali | 122 |
| 2 | john | 133 |
| 2 | john | 144 |
| 2 | john | 122 |
| 3 | mike | 111 |
| 4 | khan | 444 |
| 5 | jan | 122 |
| 5 | jan | 155 |

So I am using the above view data in oracle apex report. I want to search data by id for example I search for id=1, it contains two values in contacts column one of the value which is 122 is also included in another records so the result should also contain all the other records which contain 122 in their contacts column.
The expected result which I want is:

| id | name | contacts |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | ali | 1234 |
| 1 | ali | 122 |
| 2 | john | 133 |
| 2 | john | 144 |
| 2 | john | 122 |
| 5 | jan | 122 |
| 5 | jan | 155 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can phrase your requirement as wanting to return any record with `id = 1` or any record whose contacts overlap with the contacts of `id = 1`.

```sql
SELECT id, name, contacts
FROM yourTable
WHERE id = 1 OR
      id IN (
          SELECT id
          FROM yourTable
          WHERE contacts IN (SELECT contacts FROM yourTable WHERE id = 1)
      )
ORDER BY id;
```

[image: screen capture from demo link below]

### Demo